# Code prints numbers until 3 when it's supposed to print until 5

Tags: javascript, arrays

This code is only printing numbers until 3 when it's supposed to print numbers until 5, what's wrong?

```
function reversingwithout (array){
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        var old = array.shift(array[i])
        console.log(old);
    }
}

var hh = [1,2,3,4,5];
reversingwithout(hh);
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.shift` doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Hint: you're removing elements from the array when you use the `shift()` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `array.shift` operation is altering your array within the loop.

[Array.prototype.shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift):

> The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns
>   that element. This method changes the length of the array.

Try saving the array length in a variable beforehand:

```
var hh = [1,2,3,4,5];
var length = hh.length;
function reversingwithout (array){
    for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
        var old = array.shift()
        console.log(old);
    }
}

reversingwithout(hh);
```

Also note, that `array.shift` takes no arguments.

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/paleyifija/1/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 1):

See how the loop condition evolves among the iterations:

1. `i == 0`, `array.length == 5`. OK
2. `i == 1`, `array.length == 4`. OK
3. `i == 2`, `array.length == 3`. OK
4. `i == 3`, `array.length == 2`. End loop

I think you misunderstood `shift`. If you only want to print all items, just do something like

```
for(var i=0; i<array.length; ++i) console.log(array[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

The value of `array.length` is computed each time the loop guard is checked. The loop body, when calling `Array.shift()`, removes an element from the array, thereby decreasing the length of the array. Thus, at the time when the loop exits, `i == 3` and `array.length == 2`.

You can fix this by storing the initial value of `array.length` in a variable and using that variable in the loop guard instead.

e.g.

```
var len = array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { ...
```